# Material-UI Autocomplete clear value with active getOptionSelected

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I have a Autocomplete component provided by Material-UI:

This is the code:

```
                    <Autocomplete
                        onFocus={() => setFocusedProject(true)}
                        onBlur={() => setFocusedProject(false)}
                        onKeyDown={deleteProject}
                        className={classes.generalField}
                        id="checkboxes-tags-demo"
                        disableClearable
                        options={projects}
                        value={consistenceProject}
                        onChange={handleProjectChange}
                        getOptionSelected={(option) => option.id === consistenceProject.id}
                        getOptionLabel={(option) => (option.projectName + " - " + option.clientName)}
                        renderInput={(params) => (
                            <TextField
                                {...params}
                                error={projectError === "" ? false : true}
                                helperText={projectError}
                                variant="outlined"
                                label={i18n.t("worklogModal.project")} />
                        )}
                        renderOption={(option, { selected }) => (
                            <React.Fragment>
                                <Radio
                                    color={Colors.firstColor}
                                    className={classes.radioButton}
                                    style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
                                    checked={selected}
                                />
                                {option.projectName}
                            </React.Fragment>
                        )}
                    />
```

This is the `onChange function`:

```
 const handleProjectChange = (event, newValue) => {
        if (newValue != null) {
            setProjectValue(newValue.id)
            setConsistenceProject(newValue)
            !id && sessionStorage.setItem('worklogConsistenceProject', JSON.stringify(newValue))
            !id && sessionStorage.setItem("worklogProject", JSON.stringify([newValue.id]))
        }
    }
```

I would like if the user press the `backspace button` to clear the component. This is my function:

```
const deleteProject = (event) => {
    if (projectValue && focusedProject && event.keyCode === 8) {
            sessionStorage.removeItem('worklogConsistenceUser')
            sessionStorage.removeItem('worklogProject')
            setProjectValue()
            setConsistenceProject()
    }
}
```

It clears my values, but the problem is that it throws an `undefined` error on `getOptionsSelected` props that it can't find `id`:

[image]

How can I do it to clear my values?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SOLUTION

Might sound rookie but I changed my `handleProjectChange` to:

```
const handleProjectChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setProjectValue(newValue ? newValue.id : null)
    setConsistenceProject(newValue)
    !id && sessionStorage.setItem('worklogConsistenceProject', JSON.stringify(newValue))
    !id && sessionStorage.setItem("worklogProject", JSON.stringify(newValue ? [newValue.id] : null))
}
```

And `getOptionsSelected` prop to:

```
getOptionSelected={(option) => consistenceProject && option.id === consistenceProject.id}
```

**And it works great for both clear button action provided by Material-UI and my action to delete the whole selected option when pressed backspace**